# Charging and discharging a capacitor. Why current slows down?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current

Why current slows down after some time while charging a capacitor? We say that it's because the voltage across capacitor becomes equal to that of the battery, but that is equal in the first place.

Comment: No it is not equal in the first place. What makes you think that it is equal? No that the voltage across a capacitor is given by $V=Q/C$.

Comment: In any *real* circuit there is some resistance in series with the battery and the capacitor, and there is a voltage across the resistor when current is flowing. If a circuit diagram shows just a capacitor, a battery and a switch, and you assume they are all *ideal* components, then in theory the capacitor charges "instantaneously" when you close the switch, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about the current "slowing down".

Answer (score 2):

The voltage across the capacitor is **not** initially equal to the voltage of the battery. It is initially zero, as it was before it was connected to the battery. It does not change until the charge on its plates has changed.

According to Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, the algebraic sum of voltage drops around the circuit must always equal the voltage gain provided by the battery. What you are forgetting is that there is always some resistance in the circuit, even if this is only the small resistance of the wires. Let us call it a resistor. You are forgetting to take account of the voltage drop across this resistor.

[image]

Initially the whole of the voltage drop appears across the resistor and none across the capacitor. Charge then flows through the resistor onto the capacitor plates where it accumulates. This increases the PD across the capacitor and at the same time decreases the PD across the resistor. At every instant the sum of these 2 PDs equals the PD supplied by the battery, but one is decreasing while the other is increasing.

Finally the current has stopped flowing. The PD across the resistor is then zero while the PD across the capacitor is equal to that of the battery.

Comment: This is correct!